# shift left bit of -1

Tags: c, compilation, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

While solving problems, I stuck here thinking how the output of this program gives `ffffffff`. Since the left shift of bits should give -2. I cross-checked here [Online Calculator](http://calculator.vhex.net/calculator/bit/shift-bits-of-a-number-to-the-left) giving -2. I can see the binary value of -1 is 11111111. But how?
Also, my observance from here [Signed int conversion](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_signed_short.html?decimal=045049):

> -1 ---> 0xff --> 1111 1111
>
> -2 ---> 0xfe --> 1111 1110
>
> -3 ---> 0xfd --> 1111 1101
>
> -8 ---> 0xf8 --> 1111 1000

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   printf("%x", -1<<1);
   getchar();
   return 0;
}
```

Please tell me how the compiler looks integers below 0 when bitwise shift operators are used?

Comment: Are you asking why -1 is 11111111 and -2 is 11111110 in binary? The compiler just shifts the bits to the left, no magic there. How you interpret the bits depends on your system, but it is most likely *two's complement*. Google that.

Comment: The bahavior is undefined: "The result of E1 << E2 is .........  If E1 has a **signed type and nonnegative value**, and E1×2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; **otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned.**"

Comment: For me it's prints fffffffe -->-2 not ffffffff.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. I couldn't find the similar one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your program, it outputs “fffffffe”. However, the behavior is undefined. The C standard says that a left shift is defined only if the value being shifted is non-negative (and then only if the shift does not overflow). So, when you evaluate `-1 << 1`, a C implementation is allowed to do anything.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the undefined behaviour in this case!